# what is the wrong with this query

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
$query = "INSERT INTO patients ( username, idn, email, mobilenumber, healthcenter, height, weight, city, state ) 
    VALUES ( :name, :id, :mail, :mn, :hc, :heightv, :weightv, :cityv, :statev ) ";

//Again, we need to update our tokens with the actual data:

$query_params = array(
    ':name' => $_POST['username'],
    ':id' => $_POST['idn'],
    ':mail' => $_POST['email'],
    ':mn' => $_POST['mobilenumber'],
    ':hc' => $_POST['healthcenter'],
    ':hightv' => $_POST['height'],
    ':weightv' => $_POST['weight'],
    ':cityv' => $_POST['city'],
    ':statev' => $_POST['state']
);

//time to run our query, and create the user

try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
```

Comment: in your query_params you mispelled heightv

Comment: @chinna_82 correct the typp `':hightv' => $_POST['height'],` to `':heightv' => $_POST['height'],`

Answer (score 2):

In your query_params you mispelled `heightv`,

You should use

```
':heightv' => $_POST['height'],
```

instead of

```
':hightv' => $_POST['height'],
```